# AngularJS - Directive to append input value to a list and bind to model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

**End goal**: Associate multiple email addresses, each with a frequency setting (daily,weekly,monthly), to a notification.

I am attempting to define a directive which acts on a button element, such that, when the button is clicked, it takes the email address from the input element and the frequency from the drop-down next to the button and inserts them into a list below the input+button and binds the dynamic list to a property on the controller so it can be sent to the server when the user submits the form.

The form is all wired up - thats not the question.

I just want some help in building the directive.

Here's what i have so far:

**HTML**:

```
<section ng-controller="notificationmanagement as vm">
    <input name="email" type="email"/>
    <select>
        <option>Daily</option>
        <option>Monthly</option>
        <option>Weekly</option>
    </select>
    <button data-cm-click type="button" class="btn btn-default"></button>
    <div ng-model="vm.Subscribers"></div>
</section>
```

**Directive**:

```
commonModule.directive('cmClick', function () {
    return function (scope, element) {            
        element.bind("click", function () {

            // Is this the best way to get the value of the EmailAddress & Frequency?
            var emailAddress = element[0].parentElement.parentElement.children[0].value;
            var frequency = element[0].parentElement.parentElement.children[1].value;
            var spanEmailTag = angular.element('<span>' + emailAddress + '</span>');
            var spanFreqTag = angular.element('<span>' + frequency + '</span>');
            angular.element(spanEmailTag).appendTo(element[0].parentElement.parentElement);
            angular.element(spanFreqTag).appendTo(element[0].parentElement.parentElement);

            // How to make sure each added email+frequency is available 
            // in the array bound to 'vm.Subscribers'
        });
    }
});
```

The structure of 'vm.Subscribers' should be something like this, in order for it be consumed by the server:

```
vm.Subscribers = [ {'EmailAddress':'joe@email.com', 'Frequency':'Daily'}, {'EmailAddress':'bob@email.com', 'Frequency':'Monthly'} ];
```

**NOTE:** I would *ideally* like to achieve this without relying on jQuery within the directive.

Any and all pointers/help/advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the use of a directive is the right move here, at least as you have attempted it. It _could_ be done with a directive, but then it should contain all the data it requires, like email and frequency. Also, what is the meaning of a `<div>` with `ng-model`?

Comment: The reason I chose a directive is because I have read from numerous sources that DOM manipulation should be done in directives e.g. [http://ng-learn.org/](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/). The meaning of the `<div>` with ng-model` was my ignorant attempt at marking up an element into which the Email+Frequency instance elements can be inserted whilst at the same time binding their values to the `vm.Subscribers` array. @NewDev If directive is not the right move...any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, DOM manipulations should only be done in a directive, but DOM manipulations should be just that - manipulation of the View. What you are trying to do is to get data from the DOM, which should belong with the ViewModel. You should really read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to encapsulate and reuse some functionality, then, by all means, use a directive.

But first, understand the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) paradigm and how Angular implements this.

For starters, assume that there is no View (and so, no DOM, directives, etc...) and that user inputs *magically* occur when something is exposed on the `$scope` (or, if you are using ControllerAs - as a property of the controller). Now, build you app's functionality starting from the controller. Define the data structure and the behavior with functions.

```
app.controller("notificationmanagement", function(){
   // list of subscribers. You could also populate it from the backend. 
   this.subscribers = [];

   // this is where the details of a new subscriber will be stored
   // until subscriber is added
   this.newSubscriber = {EmailAddress: null, Frequency: null}; 

   // action to add a susbscriber
   this.addSubscriber = function(){
      this.subscribers.push(this.newSubscriber);

      // clear the object (it's not necessary to declare all the properties)
      this.newSubscriber = {};
   }
});
```

That is, in a nutshell, all your app is doing. The controller doesn't (and shouldn't) care **how** this is displayed in the View. This is why DOM manipulation is frown upon, because it breaks separation of concerns.

Now, to the View. The View is mostly declarative:

```
<section ng-controller="notificationmanagement as vm">
   <input ng-model="vm.newSubscriber.EmailAddress" type="email>
   <select ng-model="vm.newSubscriber.Frequency">
      <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
      <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
      <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
   </select>
   <button ng-click="vm.addSubscriber()"> Add </button>

   <hr/>

   <h3>All subscribers:</h3>
   <div ng-repeat="s in vm.subscribers">
      <span>{{s.EmailAddress}}</span>
      <span>{{s.Frequency}}</span>
   </div>
</section>
```

Notice how `ng-model` directives bind input data to controller's data. Notice `ng-click` that invokes an action on the controller. Notice `ng-repeat` that iterates and creates DOM elements based on that data. The View is purely driven by data, which is referred to by **ViewModel.**

Understand this first, then move onto directives.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain the correct way to achieve the desired outcome! Very helpful...hope this helps someone else too.